# Select query using Spring JDBC

Tags: database, spring-jdbc

I am executing a select statement on a table using Spring JDBC template and get this error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM EXCEPTION WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ? AND REASON LIKE ? AND SOURCE LIKE ? ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=?;ATE DESC FETCH FIRST;<space>, DRIVER=3.59.81
```

Query:

```
String qry = "SELECT * FROM ERROR" +
            " WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?" +
            " AND REASON LIKE ?" +
            " AND SOURCE LIKE ?" +
            " ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC" +
            " FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY";
```

call the query:

```
template.query(qry , new Mapperclass(),
            error.getStartDate(), error.getEndDate(), error.getReasonPattern(), exception.getSource(),
            maxNumberOfDetails);
```

The query looks fine and I don't get this error if I use hard coded value for `FETCH FIRST N ROWS`  and omit the 5th param from the query. Example:

```
String qry = "SELECT * FROM ERROR" +
            " WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?" +
            " AND REASON LIKE ?" +
            " AND SOURCE LIKE ?" +
            " ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC" +
            " FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY";
```

and

```
 template.query(qry , new Mapperclass(),
            error.getStartDate(), error.getEndDate(), error.getReasonPattern(), exception.getSource());
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's omitting the 5th parameter because you have an additional parameter, `new MapperClass`.

Since you have all 5 parameters I don't think you can add `new MapperClass()` to it. Try omitting it.

Comment: Please consider answering as if you're not sending a text message.

Comment: I need the mapper class in my query, guess the problem is sending the number of rows param in it.

Comment: I am sorry for being rude but I thought this forum is for helping people, but it looks like its for figuring out other people mistakes. FYI I was editing my answer.

Comment: yes, since your query is of 5 parameters you should only send 5 parameters only.But you are sending 6.

Comment: Answers written in text-speak aren't really what we're looking for, so I edited it. That's how SO works, and it's the responsibility of SO citizens to provide that information to newer answerers-that's what I did. Feedback is information, not an attack-being able to accept feedback is a critical soft skill and I'd encourage you to view it as such. The answer, however,  is still incorrect, as the api docs indicate. Downvoting and/or commenting on incorrect answers is also important so future visitors recognize when a solution is wrong or sub-optimal.

Comment: I solved the issue, in the query, I had FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY and for this parameter, I was providing maxNumberOfDetails as the input. The issue is this variable type is int and the template expects type String. converting it to String worked!